# [\t\s ]+\r|[\t\s ]+\n|[\t\s ]+\r|[\r\n]+ not able to catch empty lines in plain text document

Tags: regex, perl

Beginning to use perl RegExp.I am using the following RegExp to catch unwanted blank lines in a plain text document. Still some lines are left not caught. Where am I going wrong

```
[\t\s ]+\r|[\t\s ]+\n|[\t\s ]+\r|[\r\n]+
```

Comment: Correction : The expression is [\t\s ]+\r|[\t\s ]+\n|[\r\n]+

Comment: You will only catch blank lines if they contain spaces - you will not catch empty blank lines.

Comment: or maybe: \s*(?:\r\n|\r|\n) ?

Comment: Have you tried simply catching lines with `/^\s*$/`

Comment: Thank you NiematojakTomasz. This one worked. Dont know why mine didnt. Problem solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't you just use `/^\s*$/`? (a line containing zero or more white-space characters only)  You shouldn't try to match newline with `\n` or `\r`, use `$` (end of line) instead.

Comment: Followed your hint. The expression which worked was \s+[^\S].Thanks.

Comment: @Sivakumar, that regular expression will not catch empty lines but lines that contains at least two white-spaces. The `[^\S]` ("not a non-space") is just very roundabout way of saying `\s`!

Comment: I was using 'http://gskinner.com/RegExr/' to test the expression, where /^\s*$/ did not work where as \s+[^\S] did. May be something with the processing. But I will keep it in mind.

Comment: For that matter, can't you just use `!/\S/`?

Comment: @mob, that would fail on lines containing only white-space. On the other hand, if it contained white-space, it wouldn't be properly empty. If properly empty lines were to be found, then `/^$/` would be more readable.